# What is the best way of drawing massive of different objects with the same texture using JOGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

The following questions are about the coding style. (currently using JOGL + gl3)

If I want to draw a mass of different objects containing the same texture with JOGL, and to reduce the resources usage, is it better to seperate the objects and their texture (meaning that creating another class named texture), or to make the texture static in these objects?

Another question is that if I want to draw a lot of branches (say a hundred) having different shape, should I write a class named Branch, then create a hundred branch instances and call the method drawMyself() in each of them? Or create one instance containing a hundred VAO, each of which contains the vertices info of one branch and call the method drawMyself() once? Which one is better or are there any other choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you need only one instance of the texture data. After you have uploaded it to VRAM, it can be deallocated from application's memory to save space. From the OpenGL perspective, you can simply bind the texture once before you start drawing and then draw every objects that use this same texture. This is essentially one way of batching draw calls together, a very common technique in improving rendering performance.

For the second question, you should go for less method calls and less VAO. Eventhough the Hotspot JVM is extremely good at JIT-ing your code, each method call is still going to cause some overhead, not to mention overhead of OpenGL call. The best case scenario is if you know your vertices up front and they are not going to change on a per frame basis, build a single static VBO with interleaved vertex attributes, then call draw once for best performance.

Comment: I agree with your comment. I advise you to take care of the numbers of elements in the VBO. In the past, I used GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES as an hint but it's not in OpenGL ES 2 (which is supported by JOGL) and its value might not be accurate on lots of hardware.